# PHP - Function name must be a string

Tags: php, function

The error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: exec in readings.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in readings.php on line 3
```

The code:

```
<?php
    require('smarty_config.php');
    exec('reading_fetcher.py',$output,$ret_code);
    $smarty->assign('readings',$output);
    $smarty->display('readings.tpl');
?>
```

I was asked for the code of `reading_fetcher.py` so here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2, re

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://it.ctsfw.edu/inc/nc_scriptureframe.php')

html = response.read()

def remove_html_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub(' ', data)

import re
import htmlentitydefs

def convertentity(m):
    if m.group(1)=='#':
        try:
            return unichr(int(m.group(2)))
        except ValueError:
            return '&#%s;' % m.group(2)
        try:
            return htmlentitydefs.entitydefs[m.group(2)]
        except KeyError:
            return '&%s;' % m.group(2)

def converthtml(s):
    return re.sub(r'&(#?)(.+?);',convertentity,s)

readings =  converthtml(str(remove_html_tags(html)))
readings.replace("&nbsp;", " ")

print readings[699:]
```

I already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966129/fatal-error-function-name-must-be-a-string-in-php-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611709/php-error-function-name-must-be-a-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093305/fatal-error-function-name-must-be-a-string).  Two of those errors are an extra "$".  I don't see an extra "$" on my function name.  The third error is having "()" instead of "[]".  So I tried replacing them.  That didn't work.  What else might I try?

Comment: Does `function_exists('exec')` return true? (It pretty surely does, but who knows?)

Comment: @zneak It should do, otherwise he would of got `Fatal error: Call to undefined function`. (I think.)

Comment: Do you need to create `$output = array()` first?

Comment: do you have a trailling $ at the end of smarty_config.php ?

Comment: What happens if you comment away `smarty_config.php`? Do you get a different error? If so, probably that the problem is in the file.

Comment: +1 @zneak comment.  Just try running the exec command, and see if you get an error.  Then, try just only running the `require('smarty_config.php');` command by itself.  Likely, you won't get an error just running the exec, but will get one running the require.

Comment: @zneak: Commenting out `smarty_config.php` has no effect.  The error remains the same.

Comment: @sberry2A: `require('smarty_config.php')` returns true without an error.

Comment: @Ben: No there is not an extra `$` in `smarty_config.php`

Comment: @alex: Adding `$output = array();` before `exec('reading_fetcher.py',$output,$ret_code);` has no effect.  The error remains the same.

Comment: Post the code for reading_further.py and add `$ret_code=0`

Comment: @Jason: Done.  Nothing I do to `$ret_code` seems to have any effect.

Comment: Do you have safe mode enabled?

Comment: @David: According to my PHP.ini file, safe mode is off.

Comment: @David: Sorry if this is obvious, but `exec()` could have what?

Comment: @John I just wanted to write a comment but since it had no sense at all I stopped... and pressed enter without noticing.

Comment: @David: FYI, when you mouse over your comment a faint "X" appears at the end of it.  You can click this to delete it.

Comment: What if you replace exec with the backticks? like $output=`yourpythonscript.py`

Comment: @David: No change.  The error remains the same.

Comment: @John: I ran out of ideas. At least I can see nothing from the code and I can't think of a particular misconfiguration of the interpreter that would give you the same errors. Maybe some transparent or non rendered unicode character in the source where the exec line is?

Answer (score 1):

exec() could have been disabled by the server admin. In this scenario a call to exec would print an E_NOTICE and a E_WARNING. So if you disabled warning printing you can only see the E_NOTICE and potentially miss the more interesting warning saying "exec has been disabled for security reason".

You can add this line to your code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

so that you can have a more verbose execution.

Comment: Good hint, it has most likely been disabled. @OP: If you have access to php.ini, look for `disable_functions`, this is where the sysop can disable php functions.

Comment: @acme: `disable_functions` is set to nothing. @David: Error reporting is already set to `E_ALL` in php.ini so adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to my code did nothing.