# PHP Function name must be a string error on new variable

Tags: php

I am getting the error:

Function name must be a string on this code:

```
$profile_data = $user_data('first_name','last_name','email');
```

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Spurious `$` before `user_data`? With the dollar sign this syntax is calling a [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Comment: Your variable is likely an array. What were *you* trying to accomplish with that specific line?

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question. Also please provide what `var_dump($user_data);` outputs if you place it exactly above that line. A related section in the PHP manual is called [*Variable Functions*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) and might shed some light, too. What is the function (name?) you wanted to call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2966129/367456; http://stackoverflow.com/q/1611709/367456; http://stackoverflow.com/q/4093305/367456; http://stackoverflow.com/q/4859228/367456 and many other similar. You need to provide more information (see the `var_dump` etc) otherwise it's hard to say what *exactly* causes the error.

Comment: if $user_data was defined in another function you may need to call it into scope. 'global $user_data;' 
I just had this issue with $smcFunc['db_query'](...SQL here...) while working in Simple Machines. It gave me the same error on that line because without being called into scope, $smcFunc looks a lot like a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you *can* use variables as function-names, to do so requires the variable to be a string.

The variable `$user_data` sounds more like an array, or even possibly an object. If this is true, you will receive the error specified. Per the comment from @Jon, it could also be possible that `user_data()` is a method and the `$` is a typo.

If none-of-the-above helps, please all relevant code, specifically the creation of the `$user_data` variable (or a `var_dump($user_data)` output).

Comment: If `$user_data` was a variable the syntax would not be even close to legal. So it's not very likely that it is one.

Comment: Yes at least this is sort of guessing and providing a test-try answer.

Comment: @Jon I've used variables as function names plenty of times; `function test() { } $var = 'test'; $var();` will work perfectly fine.

Comment: @newfurniturey: Me too. But if that was the case here this question would not have been asked in the first place.

Comment: @Jon Check out http://codepad.org/3OXjXNy9 - same syntax as the OP and same error (minus the line-number, of course). Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying (which is very-well possible too =P).

Comment: @newfurniturey: Please read my comment more carefully. I never said this *cannot* happen.

Comment: @newfurniturey: I find this example better as OP told the variable is new: http://codepad.org/dM0Fboyo - I would assume NULL, but it's all a guessing game. Guessing is not good for debugging. And so it's better to teach good practice here.

Answer (score 0):

in php function define following

```
$profileData =  user_date('first_name','last_name','email');



function user_date($first_name,$last_name,$email){
}
```